# Get Files count from FileSystemWatcher Created event?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I'm wondering if there's a way to get the amount of files that are going to be copied? What I mean is following...
I'm writing an app that contains grid, which functions like windows explorer. When I'm drag-droping files, they are copied to a destination folder and my grid is supposed to refresh. My `FileSystemWatcher` sends me events about created files & grid refreshes, but for multiple files it refreshes multiple times =/ So is there a way to find out how many files were copied, or to get a collection of files just in one event?

Comment: no - you can get that from the drag&drop events themselves but not from `FileSystemWatcher`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the refresh less accurat an let it only refresh again after a defined time.
So it could solve this problem for all future refresh Problems and or user refreshes. I also would make the refresh time configurable and every user is happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

I would build an adapter that throttles and raises similar events after a delay.  This `ThrottlingFileSystemWatcher` would look virtually identical to a standard `FileSystemWatcher` but instead of raising an event for every file, it would queue up the files and raise an event some `TimeSpan` later (say 5 seconds, but make it configurable) and include all the files it saw in its `EventArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

I once coded a solution similar to @Austin Salonen's.

When a new file event is received, check to see if a count down timer is running.

- If not, start it
- If it is running, reset it to 3 seconds (time
  depends on file size and speed of file transfers).

When the count down timer triggers, THEN update the GUI.